# CMake add_custom_command without output

Tags: c++, cmake

What I need is filtering the *.h and *.cpp files in some directory, then format it using some script, so I write the following codes:

```
add_custom_command(

    DEPENDS ${GENERATED_STUFF}

    COMMAND find "${OUTPUT_DIR}/include/SOME_PATH" -iname *.h -o -iname *.cpp | xargs /net/binlib/lib/clang/clang-format-3.9.0 -i

    OUTPUT ?????
)
```

However, this command just modifies the existing files, so no new file outputs are generated. In this case, how can I define the output? Is there any other way to resolve this need? I only want this command to be re-executed only when file changes.

Comment: Do you want these actions to be performed **every build**? If so, use `add_custom_target` instead. If you want these actions to be executed **only when** files under *DEPENDS* are **changed**, you need to create "timestamp" file - any non-empty file, which timestamp can be compared with timestamp of dependees.

Comment: I only want these actions to be executed only when file changed. Could you provide more detailed solutions? I'm quite new to CMake. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create "timestamp" file. It will be used by build system only for extract timestamp and compare it with files under *DEPENDS*.

```
add_custom_command(
    DEPENDS ${GENERATED_STUFF}
    COMMAND find "${OUTPUT_DIR}/include/exchange_protocol" -iname *.h -o -iname *.cpp | xargs /net/binlib/lib/clang/clang-format-3.9.0 -i
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch my_file.stamp
    OUTPUT my_file.stamp
)
```

For make your `add_custom_command` work, you need to use `add_custom_target` which depends on given file.

Comment: Better use `cmake -E touch` instead of `echo`.

Comment: When wrote the answer, I thought about possible problems with *empty* file (created by `touch`). Actually emptiness shouldn't be a problem, so your suggestion is good. I have just replaced `cmake` with `${CMAKE_COMMAND}`. Thanks!